# PDFMerger in loop

Tags: php, loops, pdf

Can you guys help me,
I try to merge a pdf file with PDFMerger, this is the sample code :

```
$pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4')
->addPDF('samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2')
->addPDF('samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all')
->merge('browser', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
```

and how do I put the 'addPDF('samplepdfs/filename.pdf', '1-2')' in loop, so I can merge many pdf files in php dynamically ?

Comment: What exactly is not working with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, never used that library, but I would expect this wo work:

```
<?php
$pdfCatalog = [
    ['samplepdfs/one.pdf', '1, 3, 4'], 
    ['samplepdfs/two.pdf', '1-2'],
    ['samplepdfs/three.pdf', 'all']
];
// $pdf = ....... (instantiation of the $pdf object, missing in your code above...)
foreach ($pdfCatalog as $pdfDocument) {
    $pdf->addPDF($pdfDocument[0], $pdfDocument[1]);
}
$pdf->merge('browser', 'samplepdfs/TEST2.pdf');
```

*Note: I did not test this, but it appears logical from a normal understanding of the php syntax. It should work unless that library has been implemented totally borked...*

Comment: The only way this wouldn't work is if `addPDF` returns a new instance of the `$pdf` object instead of modifying the original instance - this is very unlikely, but to comply with OPs code `$pdf = $pdf->addPdf()` would be more correct as it would emulate the chaining. [**That said, the `addPdf()` method returns `$this`, so either would work**](https://github.com/myokyawhtun/PDFMerger/blob/master/PDFMerger.php#L61)

Comment: Thanks guys,. I implementing this using laravel 5.2,, and I got this error "ErrorException in fpdi.php line 88: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated" ..

Comment: @HendrikEka Please post that part of the file up in your question, since it is unclear what you refer to. We cannot _guess_ the content of that file...

Comment: @arkascha .. I posted below

Comment: @HendrikEka Why did you post that as an answer instead of adding it to the question? Apart from that this does not really help, since it is still unclear what line 88 in file fpdi.php actually contains.

Comment: @arkascha I don't want to make the code look messy, so I posted as an answer.. Sorry, my mistake .. here is the code from fpdi.php line 88, $this->parsers[$fn] =& new fpdi_pdf_parser($fn, $this);  .. thanks

Comment: OK, so you have your answer. Read the error message, then look at that line, draw your conclusion. "The return value of new..." Well, in that line the `new` operator indeed is used and it always returns something, namely an object, which is fine by itself, it is the purpose of that operator. The error message then states that you should _not_ use that return value in an assignment as reference, which is exactly what is done in that line. Why not? What should that assigned value refer to? There is no variable it can refer to, since the object has just been created and needs to be assigned...

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple: Use this line inside for loop

```
$pdf->addPDF()
```

and use this line after end of for loop

```
$pdf->merge('browser');
```

Example:

```
for($i=0;$i>5;$i++){
   $path = FCPATH.'uploads/pdf/';
   $pdf->addPDF($path.''.$file[$i]);
}
$pdf->merge('browser');
```

Comment: Please have a look at the other answer to this question - is there anything new you want to add? Then please edit your question to contain additional information