# How construct php loop for PDFMerger

Tags: php, loops, pdf

I'm use PDFMerger for merge pdf files.

```
<?php
include 'PDFMerger/PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf->addPDF('C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\1.pdf', '1')
    ->addPDF('C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\2.pdf', '1')
    ->addPDF('C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\3.pdf', '1')
    ->merge('file', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\TEST2.pdf');

  ?>
```

How can this structure be created with a php loop?
We have an array with the names of the files, their number is known. 
But this:

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
$pdf->addPDF('C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\worked\title.pdf', '1');
foreach($act_files as $doc)
{
    ->addPDF('C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\\'.$doc.'.pdf', '1')
}   
->merge('file', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\TEST2.pdf');
```

not worked for syntax, of course.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can chain methods (`->...->...->`) this means each method is returning a reference to the object itself. So you can split it into separate commands:

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
foreach($act_files as $doc)
{
    $pdf->addPDF('C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\\'.$doc.'.pdf', '1');
}   
$pdf->merge('file', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\rftest\app-test\docx\pdf\TEST2.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
$pdf->addPDF('relative_path_to_folder/title.pdf', '1');
foreach($act_files as $doc)
{
$pdf->addPDF('relative_path_to_folder/'.$doc.'.pdf', '1')
}   
$pdf->merge('file', 'relative_path_to_folder/finalPDF.pdf');
```

have you tried something like above ? if it still does not work, you can check the manual to see if concat is possible -> '.$doc.' might not be read

EDIT: check the double backslash in your code, should be one only I guess

see : [PDFMerger in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358646/pdfmerger-in-loop?rq=1)